# First point of entry not main destination for second time

Tags: visas, schengen

I am going to apply for the third time now for a Schengen visa. The first time, I got it from the Greek Embassy for multiple entry but, then, I changed my plans and went to Italy and Spain instead. The second time, I got the visa from the Italian Embassy and they only bave me a single entry and the Consular Officer told me that one of the reasons why it was only a single entry is because I didn't have an entry to Greece on my first Schengen visa.

Then again, this time my first point of entry was Austria, instead of Italy. I continued by train to Italy but they don't stamp passpors at the Italian border. So, my passport shows, for the second time, that I didn't enter the main destination, although I did.

How can I be sure now that my visa application will no be denied because of this? They might consider it as fraudulent because, twice, I didn't enter the country which issued the visa.

I am going to apply to Denmark for the visa, to have my wedding there. The wedding agency I hired provides visa documents, such as an invitation letter and date for the wedding. Will this help?

Comment: I rekeyed your question; all caps is shouting, and is considered impolite.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide evidence that you obeyed the terms of your visa on your second visit. Since you failed to obey them on your first visit, you should expect deeper scrutiny. Your passport stamps don't provide this evidence, so you need other things:

- Receipts from hotels.
- Train tickets.
- Your picture at Fontana di Trevi.